# (JS) Помогите с ошибкой "Unexpected strict mode reserved word"

Tags: javascript

Работать с js только начал, до этого С# и C++, понимаю, ошибка скорее всего нубская (Не судите строго).
Есть простой класс:

```
class Scissor{

    constructor(me){
        this.me;
        this.situation;
    }
}
```

Ввожу в консоль:

```
let Biggy = new Scissor(Game.creeps['Biggy']);
```

Консоль возвращает ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Biggy' of undefined
```

Biggy(Не мой код) - объект, вроде существует, его методы выполняются. 
Незнаю, что делать, гуглил уже по англ.форумам, ничего не нашёл. Почти день уже маюсь.

[image]

Comment: Выведете в консоль `console.log(Game)` и отправьте что вывело сюда.

Comment: [object Object]
     undefined

Comment: Скриншотом пожалуйста что выводит.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FmrbH_-zbG6N8J0GJ1_K24sTZ1MWn5cS

Comment: ошибка в том, что у `Game` нет свойства `creeps`

Answer (score -1):

Ошибку нашёл, исправил -

```
class Scissor{

constructor(me){
    this.me = me; // Здесь ошибка = me
    this.situation;
}
```

Однако, при повторении консольной команды:

```
let Biggy = new Scissor(Game.creeps['Biggy']);
```

Выдаёт:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

Comment: Т. е. вторая строчка тебя не смущает?